# Spin of skyrmion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, baryons, solitons, wess-zumino-witten

Baryons can be considered as solitions in Skyrme model(See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/why-are-baryons-equivalent-to-skyrmions) post.):

[image]

Such Lagrangian haven't any information about number of colors. Bosonic or fermionic nature of baryons depends on number of colors. To fix this, one can add WZW term to Lagrangian:
[image]

WZW term will affect amplitude of rotation on angle $2\pi$ by factor $\pm 1$.

Is it possible to determine the value of baryon spin, not only Bose/Fermi statistics?